# Slideshow with up and down title animation

Tags: jquery, slideshow

For a website, I have to create a slideshow that can move from the left and the right. Nothing complicated here.

However, they want me to add some animations to each pictures title. If we are sliding to the right, titles have to appear from the top of the slideshow until the middle of the slideshow.
If we slide to the left, the title have to be loaded from the bottom of the slideshow to the middle of the screen.
Some fading effects will be added to fade the old picture text.

Does any one know a plug-in, template, slideshow that allow me to add this feature?

Thanks

Comment: You can find too many of them on _Google_.

Comment: Do you have a link exemple?

Answer (score 0):

Following are some of the example links where you can find image sliders:

1. [20 of the Best jQuery Slideshow Plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-slideshow/)
2. [JQuery Slideshow Methods](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slideshow/)
3. [SlideJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/)

There may be plenty of others. You will have to manipulate them according to your requirements.